# How and why JavaScript type coercion works?

Tags: javascript, string, types, type-coercion

`var x = 5;`

If I run `console.log('The number is ' + x);`

The output is `The number is 5;`

But my question is that why the number convert into string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In type coercion, i.e comparing or calculating two operands of a different type, one of them will be converted to an equivalent type. The reason `number` is converted to `string` is because every number can be a string but the opposite can't always be true, so the type coercion always converts a number to a string

Answer (score 3):

It's simply because what you wrote in the `console.log` command outputs a string, therefore when you use `'The number is ' + x` what you're doing is essentially string concatenation.

On the other hand if you use `console.log(x)` you'd get an int response.

You can check this here:

```js
var x = 5;

console.log("The number is " + x);
console.log(typeof ("The number is " + x));

console.log(x);
console.log(typeof x);

console.log(x + x);
console.log(typeof (x + x));
```

You can check more on this in [MDN's Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types)

Comment: If you attempt to add a `Number` to a `String`, the default operation is to call `toString` on `Number` with no arguments. The default parameter is `10` (i.e., base 10) and this will convert it to a string literal `"5"` which is then concatenated to `"The number is "`. Lastly, `console.log` takes this argument and calls `util.inspect` on it, and the output of this call on a string argument, is to print the input argument in its string form, to `process.std.out`, appending a line ending to it.

An example implementation: https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#nodejs-printer-example.